# Linq-to-SQL data-retrieval speed comparison

Tags: performance, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, orm, dataset

Someone tell me why `Linq-to-SQL` is so fast to retrieve data?

I did performance tests with `Linq-to-SQL`, `EF4`, `DataSet` and `MyORM`.

`Linq-to-SQL` is always faster, see the table below:

- `Linq-to-SQL` = 570  milliseconds to retrieve 50000 records
- `DataSet` = 2.100 milliseconds to retrieve 50000 records
- `EF4` = 1.200 milliseconds to retrieve 50000 records
- `MyORM` = 700 milliseconds to retrieve 50000 records

I used SQL Server 2005 (local) and a single table for analysis.

`MyORM` was implemented by me. Is a simple method that retrieve data using `DataReader` and Fasterflect to fill properties of `IList of T`.

What is the strategy of `Linq-to-SQL` to have this performance?

Answer (score 2):

LINQ to SQL performs a number of tricks.  If your own ORM is using reflection then you'll need to cache that but I suspect the difference may be that you are not caching the ordinals.

e.g. instead of

```
while(dataReader.Read()) {
    ...
    myNewObj.SomeProperty = dataReader.GetInt32(dataReader.GetOrdinal("SomeField"));
    ...
}
```

create a variable for each ordinal and reference them inside your loop:

```
var someFieldIdx = dataReader.GetOrdinal("SomeField");
...
while(dataReader.Read()) {
    ...    
    myNewObj.SomeProperty = dataReader.GetInt32(someFieldIdx);
    ...
}
```

Even better would be to cache them on some static variables.

If you're already doing that you might want to publish some of your ORM code that instantiates objects.